# Given 3 expressions, cypher to pick unique node matching

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have lot of nodes with properties/attributes: p1, p2, p3, p4, p5 etc;

Give an array of 3 regular expressions:

```
exp1 -> p1 = 1
exp2 -> p2 = 2 OR p3 = 3
exp3 -> p4 = 4 AND p5 = 5
```

Each expression match could result with 0, 1, or more nodes.

Can you help in writing single cypher query to **pick the unique node**, if any of the above expressions could matching with exactly one node?

Return null, if all given expressions match with more than 1 node OR no nodes.

---

**What I tried?**

Right now, I am using this query and wrote application code to check if any of the collection contains unique/only one node:

```
Optional MATCH (n1) WHERE n1.p1=1 WITH COLLECT(n1) as c1
Optional MATCH (n2) WHERE (n2.p2=2 OR n2.p3=3 ) WITH c1,COLLECT(n2) as c2
Optional MATCH (n3) WHERE (n3.p4=4 AND n3.p5=5 ) WITH c0,c1,COLLECT(n2) as c3
RETURN c1,c2,c3
```

---

**What I want?**

Rather than returning collections, If any of collection contains exactly 1 node, return it OR return null.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fairly efficient query:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (n1) WHERE n1.p1=1
WITH n1 LIMIT 2
WITH COLLECT (n1) AS n1s
WITH CASE WHEN SIZE(n1s) = 1 THEN n1s[0] END AS n1

OPTIONAL MATCH (n2) WHERE n2.p2=2 OR n2.p3=3
WITH n1, n2 LIMIT 2
WITH n1, COLLECT (n2) AS n2s
WITH n1, CASE WHEN SIZE(n2s) = 1 THEN n2s[0] END AS n2

OPTIONAL MATCH (n3) WHERE n3.p4=4 AND n3.p5=5
WITH n1, n2, n3 LIMIT 2
WITH n1, n2, COLLECT (n3) AS n3s
WITH n1, n2, CASE WHEN SIZE(n3s) = 1 THEN n3s[0] END AS n3

RETURN n1, n2, n3
```

For each `WHERE` test it:

- Stops looking for more nodes as soon as it finds 2 nodes,
- Determines if a single node was found,
- Assigns either the single node or `NULL` to the appropriate variable.